# AttributeError in BeautifulSoup .text Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am using BeautifulSoup for a long long time and now every old or new script that I write, dispalys this error but this should work.

```
title = soup.find('span',{"class" : 'product-name'}).text.encode(utf-8)
```

Even if I try something like this:

```
title = soup.find('span', 'product-name').text.encode(utf-8)
```

I don't really know why this happens, it's correct. Also I have ran older scripts which worked in past, but again something went wrong with AttributeError exception. Anybody have some suggestion?

**EDIT :**

I have tried similar script with selenium, and it's working. It supports .text attribute. Also I tried replacing .text with .get_text() and again the same error. Also not recognizing import for lxml (which avoid this starting BeautifulSoup warning in the beginning of traceback)

Traceback:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 181
    markup_type=markup_type))
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 1 of the file <string>. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "html.parser")


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Uros\Desktop\Products-script\Test03.py", line 31, in <module>
    title = soup.find('span',{"class" : 'product-name'}).get_text().encode(utf-8)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Comment: Can you post a full traceback?

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: As you can see from the traceback, find returns None. So probably page doesn't contain <span class="product-name">

Comment: That's solution, I haven't saw that mistake. Thank you!

Comment: the find() will return None if there is no match. this explain the error.
i think that the website you scraping is changed since last time you run the spider.